# Defining regular expression for a big string

Tags: c#, regex

I have searched Google and still don't know how to write a regular expression  for this:

> rec-1-20151103142759-d9fd57bc-4fe3-4b91-a640-ddd54ef081dd-Speakers-Andreea.Dumitru-ANDREEADUM-DSK-9fa377fe-3290-4cb7-9c7e-6ea86e01e08f-1066

What I have to obtain from this string is the following:

- id = 1
- datetime = 20151103142759
- guidid2= d9fd57bc-4fe3-4b91-a640-ddd54ef081dd
- type= Speakers
- userName= Andreea.Dumitru
- sourceName= ANDREEADUM-DSK
- guidId2 = 9fa377fe-3290-4cb7-9c7e-6ea86e01e08f-1066

I have started with

```
Regex regex = new Regex(-[0-9]{1}(| |-)[0-9]{14}(| |-)[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(| |-)[a-fA-F](| |-)[a-fA-F](| |-) ....
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
\w{3}-(\d)-(\d{14})-([\w\d]{8}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{12})-(\w+)-([\w.]+)-(\w+-\w+)-([\w\d]{8}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{12}-[\w\d]{4})
```

This would be the line in C# without regex options:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\w{3}-(\d)-(\d{14})-([\w\d]{8}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{12})-(\w+)-([\w.]+)-(\w+-\w+)-([\w\d]{8}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{12}-[\w\d]{4})");
```

Here it is in regex101: https://regex101.com/r/bI8yH6/1

Comment: Update! guidId2 from list is actually two properties, a guidid( 9fa377fe-3290-4cb7-9c7e-6ea86e01e08f ) and a number(1066) that can have more than 4 digits.  
So i modified  regular expresion like this :  Regex regex = new Regex(@"\w{3}-(\d)-(\d{14})-([\w\d]{8}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{12})-(\w+)-([\w.]+)-(\w+-\w+)-([\w\d]{8}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{4}-[\w\d]{12})-(\d+)"); .  Maybe can help someone else too.